# How to pass unique id to every url without adding it manually

Tags: php, jquery

I need to pass a unique ID on every page when they browse the website.

Like i have a website and it has those few pages likes services, testimonials etc.
So if someone browse the website normally they cannot see the id. like
**www.example.com

www.example.com/services

www.example.com/testimonials**


Now I have a link so clicking on that the home page link got changed to
**www.example.com/?token=send12345**

So I want as if now someone clicks on the services menu or the testimonials menu the ID should go to there url like without adding the ID manually on the menu

**www.example.com/services?token=send12345

www.example.com/testimonials?token=send12345**

Is this can be done with jquery or is there anything that can work.

Thanks.

Comment: THIS IS *EXACTLY* WHAT COOKIES ARE FOR.

Comment: Read up on how to implement pretty url's. It needs to be done on server

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any link where i can found how to set those.

Comment: Do like everyone else and search that term and include `php` in it

Comment: can we see your code? do you want it in php?  does it need to be ?token=send12345 or do you want random?

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you need to write something into the session storage.

Comment: This isn't an answer ...it is nothing more than  comment. Use comment blocks not answers for comments. It is far too vague to be an answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any link where i can found how to set those.